# Dynamic height modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Tell me how to make the height of my modal dynamic. That is, so that the maximum height is 85% (as indicated in my code), but if the drop-down lists are closed (as in the initial position) or only some are open, then the height of the modal is adjusted to the appropriate sizes.

```
        const style = {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: '50%',
    left: '50%',
    transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
    width: 300,
    bgcolor: 'background.paper',
    border: '1px solid #000',
    boxShadow: 24,
    p: 4,
    overflow: 'auto',

};

export default function ModalWindow() {
    const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
    const handleOpen = () => setOpen(true);
    const handleClose = () => setOpen(false);

    return (
        <div>
            <Button onClick={handleOpen}><FilterAltIcon/></Button>
            <Modal
                open={open}
                onClose={handleClose}
                disableScrollLock= {true}
            >
                <Box sx={style}>
                    <Typography id="modal-modal-title" variant="h6" component="h2">
                        Filters
                    </Typography>

                    <Typography sx={{mt: 1}}>
                        <FilterMethod></FilterMethod>
                    </Typography>

                    <Typography sx={{mt: 1}}>
                        <FilterStatusCode></FilterStatusCode>
                    </Typography>

                    </Typography>
                </Box>
            </Modal>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Have you tried max-height property  , max-height : 85% , and remove the height property

Comment: @AkashNO yes, i tried. The max-height property is not supported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are telling the modal to occupy 85% of the viewport height. So it will occupy that 85% all the time because you are telling it to do so.

Remove the 85% height from your styles. And Write a condition that changes height from auto to 85% when your filter is open.

```
       const style = {
        position: 'absolute',
        top: '50%',
        left: '50%',
        transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
        width: 300,
        bgcolor: 'background.paper',
        border: '1px solid #000',
        boxShadow: 24,
        p: 4,
        overflow: 'auto'
       };
    
    export default function ModalWindow() {
        const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
        const [isFilterMethodExpanded, setIsFilterMethodExpanded] = React.useState(false);
        const [isFilterStatusCodeExpanded, setIsFilterStatusCodeExpanded] = React.useState(false);
        const [isFilterLinkExpanded, setIsFilterLinkExpanded] = React.useState(false);
        const [isFilterDateExpanded, setIsFilterDateExpanded] = React.useState(false);
        const handleOpen = () => setOpen(true);
        const handleClose = () => setOpen(false);
    
        return (
            <div>
                <Button onClick={handleOpen}><FilterAltIcon/></Button>
                <Modal
                    open={open}
                    onClose={handleClose}
                    disableScrollLock= {true}
                >
                    <Box sx={style} style={{ height: (isFilterMethodExpanded && isFilterStatusCodeExpanded && isFilterLinkExpanded && isFilterDateExpanded) ? '85%' : 'auto' }}>
                    <Typography id="modal-modal-title" variant="h6" component="h2">
                        Filters
                    </Typography>

                    <Typography sx={{mt: 1}}>
                        <FilterMethod isExpanded={isFilterMethodExpanded} setIsExpanded={setIsFilterMethodExpanded}></FilterMethod>
                    </Typography>

                    <Typography sx={{mt: 1}}>
                        <FilterStatusCode isExpanded={isFilterStatusCodeExpanded} setIsExpanded={setIsFilterStatusCodeExpanded}></FilterStatusCode>
                    </Typography>

                    <Typography sx={{mt: 1}}>
                        <FilterLink isExpanded={isFilterLinkExpanded} setIsExpanded={setIsFilterLinkExpanded}></FilterLink>
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography sx={{mt: 1}}>
                        <FilterDate isExpanded={isFilterDateExpanded} setIsExpanded={setIsFilterDateExpanded}></FilterDate>
                    </Typography>
                    </Typography>
                    </Box>
                </Modal>
            </div>
        );
    }


    export default function FilterStatusCode({isExpanded, setIsExpanded}) {
      const [values, setValues] = React.useState([]);
      const toggleExpand = () => {
          setIsExpanded(!isExpanded);
      };
    
      return <>
        <div className="item-toggle-statuscode" onClick={toggleExpand}>
            <h6>Status Code</h6>
            { isExpanded ? <span class="material-icons">
                arrow_drop_up
              </span> :  <span class="material-icons">
                arrow_drop_down
              </span> }
              
        </div>
        { isExpanded &&
          <div>
            <TagInput
              inputProps={{ placeholder: 'Add status code...' }}
              values={values}
              onChange={(values) => {
              setValues(values)}}>
            </TagInput>
          </div>
        }
    </>;
    }

      export default function FilterStatusCode({isExpanded, setIsExpanded}) {
      const [values, setValues] = React.useState([]);
    
      const toggleExpand = () => {
          setIsExpanded(!isExpanded);
      };
    
      return <>
        <div className="item-toggle-statuscode" onClick={toggleExpand}>
            <h6>Status Code</h6>
            { isExpanded ? <span class="material-icons">
                arrow_drop_up
              </span> :  <span class="material-icons">
                arrow_drop_down
              </span> }
              
        </div>
        { isExpanded &&
          <div>
            <TagInput
              inputProps={{ placeholder: 'Add status code...' }}
              values={values}
              onChange={(values) => {
              setValues(values)}}>
            </TagInput>
          </div>
        }
    </>;
    }

        export default function FilterLink({isExpanded, setIsExpanded}) {
      const [values, setValues] = React.useState([]);
    
      return (
        <div>
          <div className="item-toggle-link" onClick={() => setIsExpanded(!isExpanded)}>
            <h6>Link</h6>
            {isExpanded
              ? <span class="material-icons"> arrow_drop_up </span>
              : <span class="material-icons"> arrow_drop_down </span>
            }
          </div>
          {isExpanded && <TagsInput tags={values} setTags={setValues} inputPlaceholder="Enter a link"/>}
        </div>
      );
    }

        export default function FilterDate({isExpanded, setIsExpanded}) {
      const [values, setValues] = React.useState([]);
    
      return (
        <div>
          Date component
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Comment: Can you tell me what code you need to show a working example?

Comment: I understand you need the FilterMethod and FilterStatusCode code. I will now supplement my question with one of these functions. One will be enough for you to show, and I will do the rest myself.

Comment: Yes, it works. Thank you. But there is a small bug. When I open the dropdown list (in our case, FilterStatusCode), provided that everything else is closed, the modal window opens immediately to 85% of the height. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Sir. I think you should add all the open filter states inside the parent component as I have made with status code. And the condition should be that if all the filters are open the modal occupies 85% of the height. If not. it should occupy the needed height. If you provide the code for the other filters I can update my code. But I think you already have a good idea how to make it. If the answer has helped you please do accept it as a valid answer. Thank you very much

Comment: I marked your answer. Thanks for helping me. But I would be grateful if you added to the code the functionality that was described in the message above. I have updated the question. I will describe the problem again for understanding: at the moment, if all the components of the modal window are closed, and I click to open one of them, then the modal window opens immediately at 85%. And I would like it to be opened as needed.